# Could a long time in storage cause my Black+Decker circular saw to lose power?

Tags: powertools, circular-saw

I have a 15amp Black+Decker Circular Saw about 8-10 years old (with a cord). I used it once when it was first purchased, and it has been stored ever since.  I went to cut a 2x4, plugged it in and the saw seemed to run fine, the blade turns, but as soon as it hits the board to cut, the saw loses power/blade stops turning. There are no issues with the plug, wiring, etc.

Could something have happened to the motor while it sat idle for so long?

Comment: Take the blade off and lay it on a flat surface to see if it's warped (bent slightly).  Other than that, do you have the correct blade for the material you're attempting to cut?

Comment: Does the motor continue to turn? The connection between blade and motor shaft may have loosened up over that long a time. Blade may just need to be tightened back on, or you may need new blade washer set.

Comment: All due respect, are you sure you know how to cut with this saw? If you ask too much of it, you'll abruptly stall the machine, especially if your sense of feeds and speeds has been miseducated by using a more powerful saw or a sharper blade.  But it should spin up again once you are free of the work.

Comment: If the blade stops but the motor keeps making noise, probably the blade is loose on the shaft. A partly-loose blade can seem like a loss of power, Its happened to me.